# Django some css not working in production

Tags: python, html, css, django, production

I have a django app. In production I ran `collectstatic` and all good except a small piece of css. This css thing is a question mark which on hover shows some tips about the app feature.
This also could be a nginx configuration issue maybe. But again, just this piece of css does not work properly.

html

```
<div class="help-tip">
 <p> 
    some text
 </p>
</div>
```

css

```
/*-------------------------
    Inline help tip
--------------------------*/
.help-tip-wrapper{
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.help-tip{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BCDBEA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    cursor: default;
}

.help-tip:before{
    content:'?';
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
}

.help-tip:hover p{
    display:block;

    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;

}

.help-tip p{
    display: none;
    background-color: #1E2021;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    right: -4px;
    color: #FFF;
  font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
    line-height: 1.4;
  position: relative;
}

.help-tip p:before{
    content: '';
    width:0;
    height: 0;
    border:6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
    right:10px;
    top:-12px;
}

.help-tip p:after{
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    content:'';
    top:-40px;
    left:0;
}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

All css working fine except this one.

Comment: Did you load your static file in your template?

Comment: what do you mean? `collectstatic` comamnd?

Comment: no! load your static CSS location in template like `{% load static %}`  and  `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/abc.css' %}">` also can you please show us your whole template file for regarding help tips

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Did it not get found by collectstatic, does it not get served, is it being loaded but the actual CSS styles are not being applied?

Comment: *just this piece of css does not work properly* - Does that mean other CSS code work fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `settings.py` file is wrong.

It should look like this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Also you have to now update your `nginx` or `apach2` server with above change  `'staticfiles'`

When you run `collectstatic` command, it will now save your bundle in `staticfiles` dir and it will be served when your `DEBUG=False` . If your debug=True, then it will server from `static` folder

Comment: I have updated everything and still not working

Comment: when I look into the css loaded from browser, there is the file but some of the css content is not there

Answer (score 0):

You have not used the url mapping for "collectstatic". So in you settings, use this kind of mapping. (can edit as you wish,except the keyword(varaible name))

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[BASE_DIR / 'static']
STATIC_ROOT= BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

After this, run the 'collectstatic'. You will get all the css, in this in production, in this specific url mapped file .